# Use a shared JSON class on Server and Client

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, gwt

I want to create a shared class on GWT client and server which uses `org.json.*` on the server side and `com.google.gwt.json.client.*`on the client side.

My shared class is something like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

class SomeDto {

   public fromJSON (JSONObject x) } 
   }
}
```

This works fine on the server side but on the client side `JSONObject` should be replaced by `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`.

**How can I use a shared JSON class on Server and Client, which uses different JSON implementations on client and server?**

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson for example? This lib is easy to use to ser/deser java objects to JSON.

Comment: I need to work it on pure Java like on Android as well as GWT.

Comment: OK. Wouldn't it be simpler to handle ser/deser *outside* of your DTO class? E.g. `SomeDtoServerSerializer` would use `org.json.JSONObject`, and `SomeDtoClientSerializer` would use `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`.

Comment: @Simon-Pierre To be specific it is all client code. It should be the same which is used on Android and on GWT.

Answer (score 0):

You have some implementations which work in client and server side:

- Elemental Json is an entire implementation in java which works in server and client sides, take a look to its [test cases](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/elemental/tests/elemental/json/JsonUtilTest.java) to figure out how it works. It is very light weight and makes use of browser native optimisations in client side.
- GwtQuery has a data binding implementation for json objects. It works in both sides and performs very well. Just define an interface extending JsonBuilder and you can share it in server and client. Take a look to this [test](https://github.com/manolo/gquery/tree/master/gwtquery-core/src/test/java/com/google/gwt/query/client/dbinding) class to see the usage or to its [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBindinghttp://). BTW gquery uses elemental json in order not to depend on the controversial `json.org` library.
- Finally the classical [AutoBeans](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html) in GWT is an option to handle JSON and bind it to POJOs. IMO it needs so much boiler-plate code.